# Unable to locate package python3.4-venv

Tags: package-management, 18.04, python3

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04.1, and am trying to install `python3-venv`.  I have tried all of the following:

```
sudo apt install python3-venv
sudo apt install python3.4-venv
sudo apt-get install python3-venv
sudo apt-get install python3.4-venv
sudo apt-get install -y python3-venv
sudo apt-get install -y python3.4-venv
```

All of the above with `3.4` result in `Unable to locate package python3.4-venv`.

All of the above with `3` result in:

```
Package python3-venv is not available, but is referred to by another package.  
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source.
E: Package 'python3-venv' has no installation candidate
```

I had the same problem with `python3-pip`, but managed to install it by `curl`ing the source.  I think this fact is a key detail to the problem, but I don't know what problem that detail points to.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @N0rbert thank you so much, that was the problem.  Now to figure out the unmet dependencies...

Comment: Dependency problems will be fixed after `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install -f`.

Comment: @N0rbert unfortunately, that didn't fix it.  I still get `python3-venv` depends on `python3 (=3.6.5-3) but 3.6.5-3ubuntu1 is to be installed`.  I'm guessing that means I need to rename `3.6.5-3ubuntu1` properly? If so, how do I do that?

Comment: Check all your repositories. Run `update` and `dist-upgrade` (to get new dependencies). See https://askubuntu.com/a/142808/66509 . If it does not help - ask new question.